# Problem with install android studio for emulator for react-native environment on mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

Im trying to install android studio for emulator for react-native environment (mac).
Im doing it with the official website:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

The 3 step is:
3. Configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

The React Native tools require some environment variables to be set up in order to build apps with native code.

Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc (if you are using zsh then ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc) config file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

But when I trying to find ~/.zprofile or ~/.zshrc (Im using zsh) I cant fint it.
In addition the emulator working but when Im running 'num run android' it fail and not connect to the emulator.

I will happy for some help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether your emulator is working for an android project. Create a basic android app and try to build it on your emulator. If it is working then your environment set up is correct.  Confirm that first.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. 
I did what you said, create android project in visual studio, and run the project with the emulator and it's work.
How to continue from here?

Comment: try to run the android app  from your react native project from android studio, not from the command line or terminal, just open the android folder from android studio

Comment: means your android development environment setup is correct. now you have to try run your android app from android studio, android app from the previously failed react project

Comment: sorry, I said that I create android project in visual studio, but it was in android studio and work. now I tried to open my react native project (the android folder) and I got  an error while running: 
Attribute "theme" bound to namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was already specified for element "activity".

Comment: That is a different error, better to open a new question thread with that specific error

Comment: but did I make it with the good way? just open the 'android' folder from react native app in android studio